# Can Netty be integrated with ZeroMQ?

Tags: java, asynchronous, network-programming, netty, zeromq

ZeroMQ (0MQ) seems to be a framework for different threads ("workers") to communicate with each other. Since Netty is an asynchronous/concurrent network programming framework, I'm wondering if there is a way to use 0MQ on the server-side with Netty for better or more reliable performance. In other words, does a server-side integration between Netty and 0MQ make sense? If not, why? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3):

Spotify has open sourced a library netty-zmtp (https://github.com/spotify/netty-zmtp) that can help.

Comment: Thanks @Boris Pavlovic (+1) - so what is gained by integrating 0MQ on the backend if Netty is already concurrent and asynchronous?

Comment: 0MQ will remove the coupling between machines. Imagine a method opening transaction in machine A, calling a machine B's method which opens a transaction in machine B -- without a serious app server it would be hard managing this distributed tx. Much easier is to do some work on machine A, put it in the 0MQ, have the machine B consume the message, do some work and put back the result to 0MQ for the A or some other machine to consume it...